# How can I make the background color of tab spacing=NONE in vim?

Tags: vim

When using vim in gnome-terminal using a tranparent background My color scheme is applying a black background to the tab spacing.

[image]

in gnome-terminal I am using `background color=tranparent`
My vim colorscheme by default applies a solid color, so I in order to achieve transparency i.e. to be able to see through both vim and gnome-terminal I have needed to use:

```
file: ~/.vimrc
"
hi Normal ctermbg=none
highlight NonText ctermbg=none
```

How can I remove the black background of the tabspaces and just have `background=none`?

I have tried `:hi TabLineFill ctermbg=none`  - no luck
Sytem Info:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- gnome-terminal
- tmux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:help 'listchars'` documents the highlight groups used:

> The "NonText" highlighting will be used for "eol", "extends" and
>     "precedes".  "SpecialKey" for "nbsp", "space", "tab" and "trail".

So, you need this additional colorscheme change:

```
highlight SpecialKey ctermbg=none
```

Comment: Glad I could help. Please don't forget to accept my answer by clicking on the outlined checkmark next to it!